# GAMS & Python: how to rewrite output gdx file while run GamsJob in loop

Tags: python, gams-math

In my task I need to run the same GAMS model with different parameters values in Python. For that I created GAMS workspace, model, job and GDX database:

```
model = '''Variables 
        objective, {vars};
    Parameters
        {up_bounds}; {low_bounds};
    $gdxin db
    $load {load_values}
    $gdxin
    Equations  
        obj, {eqs_list};
        obj ..    objective =e= {obj_equation};
        {nodes_eq};
        {up_bounds_eq};
    Model myLP /all/;
    Solve myLP using lp minimizing objective;'''.format(load_values=' '.join(load_values), kwargs**)
ws = GamsWorkspace(working_directory='some_path')

db = ws.add_database('db')
load_values_p = [self.db.add_parameter(value, 0).add_record() for value in load_values]

job = ws.add_job_from_string(model)

for i in range(any_count):
    update_parameters_values()
    job.run(databases=self.db)
    result.append([job.out_db[key][()].level for key in res_values_names])
```

where:
`load_values` - list of variables names, which will be load from 'db.gdx'. They also initialized in `Parameter` section of the `model`;
`update_parameters_values()` - function which change `load_values_p` values (it also automatically changes in `db` object and db.gdx file);
`res_values_names` - list of result variables names.

The problem is that `job` generates new out_db GDX file on every iteration, but I want to rewrite existing one and just read updated result values. How to do that? Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in GAMS documentation - GamsModifier can solve my problem. Applying it to my task and code above:

```
model = '''Variables 
        objective, {vars};
    Scalars
        {up_bounds}; {low_bounds};
    Equations  
        obj, {eqs_list};
        obj ..    objective =e= {obj_equation};
        {nodes_eq};
        {up_bounds_eq};
    Model myLP /all/;'''.format(kwargs**)
ws = GamsWorkspace(working_directory='some_path')

cp = ws.add_checkpoint()
master_init_job = ws.add_job_from_string(model)
master_init_job.run(checkpoint=cp)
mi = cp.add_modelinstance()

load_values = [mi.sync_db.add_parameter(load_value, 0)
               for load_value in load_values]

modifiers = [GamsModifier(load_value) for load_value in load_values]
mi.instantiate('myLP using lp minimizing objective', modifiers=modifiers)

for load_value in self.load_values:
    load_value.add_record()

for i in range(any_count):
    update_parameters_values()
    mi.solve()
    result.append([mi.sync_db.get_variable(key)[()].level 
                   for key in res_values_names])
```

At the time of the start, the values of all variables are similar to listed in the question.
This implementation avoids the creation of additional files and works faster.